# Add strings to listbox in WPF using C# in a thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, listbox, runtime

I want to display the path of each file when a button is pressed.
What I have right now is a function that iterates through a folder and displays the paths, but only when the function is finished:

```
public void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory)
{
    // Process the list of files found in the directory.
    try
    {
        var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);

        foreach (var fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            ProcessFile(fileName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
    try
    {
        var subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);

        foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
}


public void ProcessFile(string path)
{
    myListBox.Items.Add(path);  
}
```

This means that I have to wait before I can do something else.
How can I display the path of a file instantly when the function is running, so i don't have to wait before the function is finished, getting all the paths before displaying in the listbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember where I came across this piece of code, but if you modify your ProcessFile method to something like this it will update your UI after each item is added to your list.

```
public void ProcessFile(string path)
{
    myListBox.Items.Add(path);
    myListBox.ScrollIntoView(myListBox.Items[myListBox.Items.Count-1]);
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate { }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

I think I remember reading somewhere that this "hack" is not recommended due to a number of other problems that might occur, but I can't remember what it was or where I read it. It does the job however.

Maybe someone else can enlighten us about what these problems are...

Comment: It works just fine :) but as you said.. problems might accur.. Can anyone tell me what the problems can be and how I can fix this?

Comment: I'll be doing this until someone yells at me :) thanks for the code snippet!

Comment: How do you stop the thread after starting it? Or terminate the thread?

Comment: You can stop the foreach loop in your ProcessDirectory method by adding a flag and checking it in the loop. Add a button or something that changes the flag which will break the loop to stop adding items to the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

This makes your method run on another thread:

```
public void StartProcessThread(string targetDirectory)
{
    Thread T = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ProcessDirectory));

    T.Start(targetDirectory);
}

public void ProcessDirectory(object objTargetDirectory)
{
    string targetDirectory = (string)objTargetDirectory;

    // Process the list of files found in the directory.
    try
    {
        var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);

        foreach (var fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            ProcessFile(fileName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
    try
    {
        var subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);

        foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
}


public void ProcessFile(string path)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
        myListBox.Items.Add(path);  
    }));
}
```

Comment: Tried your example but i get this error: "Delegate constructor in invoked with 0 argument(s)". Tried this afterwards, but then it does what I don't want it to do: Dispather.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { myListBox.Items.Add(path); }));

Comment: Isn't it a lambda expression of what i've tried? But no sorry it doesn't work :/ Still have to wait before the function is finished

Comment: yes, that's correct. Maybe the listbox needs some kind of update or invalidate. You could try the ScrollIntoView from the answer below

Comment: The answear from Eirik works great, but as he mensured, problems might accur :/ but i'll give it a try until somebody can enlight me of the problems :) thanks for the effort and help!